# ASP.NET - Can you use Dynamic Data without Linq to SQL?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I have an application that creates database tables on the fly.
I'd like to create an interface to CRUD this data.
But because the tables are created as the application runs,  I can’t create the Linq to SQL classes by dragging them onto the designer.
However, I do know in my code what the tables I want to edit are.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to supply a feed to Dynamic Data via:

1. SQL query
2. Or a DataSet,

Rather than the Linq to SQL paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not a possibility.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488545.aspx) :

> *It does this by automatically discovering the LINQ-to-SQL or Entities Framework data model at run time*

There is an MVC version coming but that will have similar limitations.

There may be some way you can create a workaround for your situation since you do have tables at some point but I'm unsure without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, DD works with Linq to SQL and Entity Framework.  For your problem, it seems neither would be very helpful.